# Disable Tumblr photosets or change the size of them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I have been able to make my photos large for single photo posts on my blog, **http://blog.seans.ws**, but Tumblr photosets limit me to a width of 500px

How can I either make the layout of photosets larger, or just diable the feature and display my photos in high-res one after the other? Here's the photoset code:

```
             {block:Photoset}
                 <article>
                    <span class="break" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"></span>
                    {Photoset-500}
                    {block:Caption}
                        <p>{Caption}</p>
                    {/block:Caption}
                    <p></p>
                    <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
                </article>
            {/block:Photoset}
```

and here's the single photo code, where I am able to make photos huge:

```
            {block:Photo}
                <article>
                    <span class="break"></span>
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
                    <p>{Caption}</p>
                    <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
                </article>
            {/block:Photo}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really not necessary to use Javascript & the Tumblr API.

You can go through the Photos in each Photoset individually using the {block:Photos}.

Eg in your Example:

```
{block:Photoset}
     <article>
        <span class="break" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"></span>

        <!-- Go through each Photo in the Photoset -->
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
        {/block:Photos}

        {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
        {/block:Caption}
        <p></p>
        <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
    </article>
{/block:Photoset}
```

Remember, the [Documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts) is your friend :)

Comment: Ah, yeah I totally missed that Felix. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add this script before the ending body tag. This will increase or decrease the size of the photoset

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //This will change the source address and display the correct size.
                $(".photoset").each(function() { 
            var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace('700','860');
            $(this).attr("src", newSrc);       
        });
    //This will get the new size of the iframe and resize the iframe holder accordingly.
        $(function(){
        var iFrames = $('.photoset');
        function iResize() {
            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 
                iFrames.load(function(){
                    setTimeout(iResize, 0); 
                });

                for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
                }
            } else {
                iFrames.load(function() {
                    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep Tumblr's photoset grid style, check out this little jQuery plugin: https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset

It extends Tumblr's default photoset with EXIF data, rounded corners, different gutter sizes, etc.

Disclaimer: I had a little part in helping create it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This guy solved it :)

https://github.com/ram-nadella/Tumblr-Photoset-Alternative/blob/master/mod.html