# Tumblr: Using high-res photos in text posts

Tags: themes, photo, tumblr

When creating custom themes for Tumblr, it is possible to use high-res photos for photo posts and [photo sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963932/disable-tumblr-photosets-or-change-the-size-of-them). I was wondering whether it is also possible to embed pictures wider than 500px in my normal text posts?
So far, code like this is only limited to photo posts:

```
{block:Photos}
   <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
{/block:Photos}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can paste high-res photos with normal WYSIWYG editor.

This Tumblr code simply output all stuff included to the post.

```
{block:Text}
    {Body}
{/block:Text}
```

Did you tried this? What happens?

Comment: Hey, thanks, but as this code is the standard code for a text posts, I already tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe it's just not possible? But that'd be strange, too.

Comment: @Christoph Do you can't paste high-res photo? Or photos are not visually identical to high-res in your theme? Please clarify the problem and give us link to your Tumblelog.